# Generate list of numbers T*U and filter every other in each branch of T starting with index 0

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to generate array of numbers and get only numbers in green. How can I proceed?
[image: img]

This is to filter specific points from an array in grasshopper rhino. This is what I tried.

```
t = 4
u = 11
b = []

for i in range(t*u):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        b.append(i)
print(b)
```

I want to get out numbers (highlithed green in image)

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]
```

not this

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42]
```

Comment: You only want the numbers whose remainder after division by 11 is even which can be written as `(i % 11) % 2 == 0`.

Comment: thanks for perfect response, what if i would want to additionally skip every 11th number? [10, 21, 32]

Comment: @Grasshoperist check the end of my answer to skip also every 11th number. You should add also this information in the question: many good answers are invalidated by this requirement

Comment: @Gsk thanks for the great answer. You really explained it well. Skipping 11th number was hypothetical question (that may or may not happen as I realised later) and I dont want to change original post as it helped me through.

Comment: @Grasshoperist I'm glad it helped; with this structure you'll be able to add any condition you prefer. Just ask if you need more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
t = 4
u = 11
b = [x for x in range(t*u) if (x%u)%2 == 0]

print(b)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]`

---

**EXPLANATION:**
You want a range, from `0` to `u`.
This range will be repeated `t` times.

If you consider `t == 1`, you want to take alternate numbers. Since you always start from `0`, this means all the even number (thus `n%2 == 0`).

If you had a second loop (`t == 2`), it would be a range from `0+u` to `u+u`. Since we want to take this range to a known condition (`range(0,u)`), so we can apply `n%2 == 0`, we divide by `u` each integer in our iteration, so the rest correspond to the value in the same step in `range(0,u)`.

---

**EXAMPLE:**

- We can take all the numbers in the full range (`t*u`):

  `full_range = [x for x in range(t*u)] # output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...43]`
- Reduce all these numbers to the basic range (`range(0,u`):

  `basic_range = [y%u for y in full_range]`

which outputs:

> `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

- Check even numbers:
  `even_numbers = [z%2 == 0 for z in basic_range]`

which outputs:

> `[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]`

---

You can see that the indexes with `True` are those of the numbers you want to pick; so if you apply these conditions to your full range (`range(0,t*u)`) and pick only the integers that satisfy your conditions, you'll have your number's list.

---

**In a comment you've expressed the need to skip also every 11th number.**
following the previous explanation, we can add the condition `(x%u) != 10`:

```
[x for x in range(t*u) if (x%u)%2 == 0 and (x%u) != 10]
```

which outputs:

> `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do this using iteration, it makes more sense to tackle it column by column.

```
t = 4
u = 11
result = []
for col in range(t):
    result.extend(range(col*u, (col+1)*u, 2)) #run through 11 numbers starting from the offset of col*u (0*11, 1*11, 2*11 and so on) with an step size of 2.
print(result)
#Output:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[i + 11*n for n in range(4)] for i in range(0, 11, 2)]`

will return:

```
[[0, 11, 22, 33],
 [2, 13, 24, 35],
 [4, 15, 26, 37],
 [6, 17, 28, 39],
 [8, 19, 30, 41],
 [10, 21, 32, 43]]
```

If you want it in the one plain list, use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    zip(*[
        [i + 11*n for n in range(4)]
        for i in range(0, 11, 2)
    ])
))
```

will return:

`[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]`

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[[i + 11*n for n in range(4)] for i in range(0, 30, 2)]))`

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.chain` to the rescue!

You have 4 consecutive sequences from 11*i to 11*(i+1) stepping 2:

```
result = list(itertools.chain(*(range(11*i, 11*(i+1), 2) for i in range(4))))
```

It gives:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]
```

Answer (score 0):

This series can also be expressed as f(n) = 2n - n//6

```
r = [2*i - i//6 for i in range(24)]

# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43]
```